# Convert to Design Interface

Tags: c#, interface

We currently have a login structure but we would like to replace it with another structure. However, we would like to keep both incase the new structure will not work.

What we have right now

PasswordControl.cs

```
public class PasswordControl
{
   public passwordControl()
   {
      // code here
   }
   public doLogin()
   {
      // code here
   }
}
```

Main.cs

```
provide void btnLogin()
{
  passwordControl pw = new passwordControl();
  pw.doLogin();
}
```

We would like to convert this to a design structure

IloginManager.cs

```
Interface ILoginManager 
{
  void dologin();
}
```

so we can also add the second structure

PasswordControl2.cs

```
public class PasswordControl2
{
   public passwordControl()
   {
      // code here
   }
   public doLogin()
   {
      // code here
   }
}
```

How do I need to modify the code in Main.cs to take advantage of this new design?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: is this ASP, winforms, WPF?

Comment: Your password controls have to implement the ILoginManager interface.

Comment: It will be win Forms

Comment: Ummm... what? Are you asking how to implement a strategy pattern?

Comment: Kind of trying to understand the structure. Never used interfaces before.. The code is very simplified version of what we actually do. But i want to understand the common way of doing this, how things are being called, implemented.

Comment: Do you understand inheritance and polymorphism? An interface is just a special kind of class that you derive from.

Comment: I do understand it. 
Is this how it supposed to be. I will have the interface class
IloginManager with doLogin() method. 

public class PasswordControl:ILoginManager
{}
------------------
public class PasswordControl2:ILoginManager
------------
main class
we still do 
passwordControl pw = new passwordControl();
pw.doLogin();

but this doesn't make sense to me. I feel like interface should be used in main.cs?

Comment: You are correct in that guess. Please let me know if my answer helps, and I'll try to edit your question so its a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to alternate between various implementations of the same contract in a runtime and that's why you want to use interface. Interface is a contract: if some class implements some interface, it provides services defined in that interface. If any class implements `ILoginManager` interface, that class contains public `doLogin()` method.

```
public interface ILoginManager 
{
    void doLogin();
}

public class PasswordControl : ILoginManager
{
   public PasswordControl()
   {
      // code here
   }
   public void doLogin()
   {
      // code here
      Debug.WriteLine("PasswordControl.doLogin()");
   }
}

public class PasswordControl2 : ILoginManager
{
   public PasswordControl2()
   {
      // code here
   }
   public void doLogin()
   {
      // code here
      Debug.WriteLine("PasswordControl2.doLogin()");
   }
}
```

You said that you want to determine `ILoginManager` implementation when you are creating form. Your form can for example read the choice from the configuration file. This means that you don't have to recompile your program when want to change the contract implementation, you simply have to change the configuration file and restart the program.

Your form could have the following constructor:

```
public class MyForm
{
   ILoginManager _loginManager;

   public MyForm()
   {
      // let's assume read value is 2
      int choice = ReadChoiceFromConfigFile();

      if (choice == 1)
      {
         _loginManager = new PasswordControl();
      }
      else
      {
         _loginManager = new PasswordControl2();
      }
   }
}
```

So when you press the Login button, a proper implementation is used:

```
private void btnLogin()
{
   // in our case PasswordControl2.doLogin() is called as _choice has been set to 2
   _loginManager.doLogin();
}
```

Even better would be if responsibility of creation proper `LoginManager` would be taken out of `MyForm` as form should not know details about it - all it wants to get is an object which implements `ILoginManager` but it should not care how it's made. So ideally, you'll create `ILoginManager` implementer before creating a form and then you'd pass it as form's dependency (you would "inject" it, via constructor for example; read about [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)). That would look like this:

```
public class MyForm
{
   ILoginManager _loginManager;

   public MyForm(ILoginManager loginManager)
   {
      if (loginManager == null)
      { 
         throw new ArgumentNullException("loginManager");
      }

      _loginManager = loginManager;
   }
} 

public static void Main()
{
   ILoginManager loginManager = CreateLoginManager();
   Application.Run(new MyForm(loginManager));
}

// factory method - it creates desired instance which implements given interface
public static CreateLoginManager()
{
   ILoginManager loginManager = null;

   // let's assume read value is 2
   int choice = ReadChoiceFromConfigFile();

   if (choice == 1)
   {
       loginManager = new PasswordControl();
   }
   else
   {
       loginManager = new PasswordControl2();
   }

   return loginManager;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To utilize an interface, first have each implementation derive from it. Then in the client code, store it off as the interface type:

```
ILoginManager login = new PasswordControl();
//Do stuff with login
```

If you decide to use the other implementation, just switch what you instantiate:

```
ILoginManager login = new PasswordControl2();
//Do stuff with login
```

The subsequent code will still be fine, since you are still accessing the class through the `ILoginManager` interface. In production code, the interface will usually just be passed to you by some class higher up the call stack, or a DI container.